# Facebook graph API post to user's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the FB graph api to post content to the user's wall. I orginally tried using this method:

```
$wall_post = array(array('message' => 'predicted the',  'name' => 'predicted the'), 
                array('message' => $winning_team, 'name' => $winning_team, 'link' => 'http://www.sportannica.com/teams.php?team='.$winning_team.'&amp;year=2012'),
                array('message' => 'to beat the', 'name' => 'to beat the',),
                array('message' => $losing_team, 'name' => $losing_team, 'link' => 'http://www.sportannica.com/teams.php?team='.$losing_team.'&amp;year=2012'),
                array('message' => 'on '.$game_date.'', 'name' => 'on '.$game_date.''),
                array('picture' => 'http://www.sportannica.com/img/team_icons/current_season_logos/large/'.$winning_team.'.png'));

        $res = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', '$wall_post');
```

But, much to my surprise, you can't post multiple links to a users wall.

So, now I'm using the graph api to post content to a user's wall much like the way spotify does. So, now I've figured out that I need to create custom actions and objects with the open graph dashboard. So, I've created the "predict" action and gave it permission to edit the object "game."

So, now I have the code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'appID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user != 0) 
{
    curl -F 'access_token='$.access_token.'' \
     -F 'away_team=New York Yankees' \
     -F 'home_team=New York Mets' \
     -F 'match=http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/predict-edit-add:predict'
}
```

I keep getting an error reading:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not a shell scripting language. You cannot simply throw in a shell command and expect it to work.

Instead of trying to call the `curl` program (you'd do that e.g. with [`system()`](http://php.net/system) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec)) you can simply use the [curl PHP extension](http://php.net/curl) or an appropriate function from the Facebook API.

Answer (score 1):

You mixing PHP code and execution of `curl` command, you should either call it from shell:

```
curl -F 'access_token='$.access_token.'' \
 -F 'away_team=New York Yankees' \
 -F 'home_team=New York Mets' \
 -F 'match=http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/predict-edit-add:predict'
```

Or to achieve the same using PHP-SDK:

```
$facebook->api('/me/predict-edit-add:predict', 'post', array(
  'away_team'=>'New York Yankees',
  'home_team'=>'New York Mets',
  'match'=>'http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237'
));
```

Comment: So, will this allow me to post multiple links and an image in a wall post?

Comment: The PHP-SDK code that you wrote doesn't post anything to my wall. I just tried it.

Comment: I noticed on my open graph dashboard that none of my actions have been submitted. I tried to submit them all but apparently I need to post at least one of each action to my timeline first before they can be submitted. But, I don't even know how to post them to my feed...

Comment: PHP code I've posted should only post action for authorized user, same can be done by running the `curl` command with arguments in command line. Before actions submitted they only can be published by developers of application. What error you get while posing the action?

Comment: I am an authorized user... I'm the creator of the app. I'm not getting any errors. I'm just looking at my feed and nothing from my app is showing up on my wall.

Comment: every call `$facebook->api` return something, generally the error why if failed or some data on success.

Comment: Okay, so upon further scrutiny, I get the error reading:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: winning_team.

Comment: New error: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3503) "New York Mets" is an invalid value for property "winning_team" with type "Reference" thrown in

Comment: Obviously you should provide correct data types for action properties (URL for references).

Comment: I caught on to that. Changed it. And now I have the error reading: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.